# twilio The requested resource was not found

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

I tried to get a list of all conferences via Twilio PHP helper library, but get 404 error. My code:

```
$client = new Client($accountSid, $authToken);
foreach ($client->conferences->read() as $conference) {
    var_dump($conference);
}
```

Error:

```
[HTTP 404] Unable to fetch page: The requested resource /2010-04-01/Accounts/twilio.account_sid/Conferences.json was not found
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Are your `$accountSid` and `$authToken` correct?

Comment: $accountSid and $authToken is taken from https://www.twilio.com/console "Project info" tab

Comment: can you try this $conferences = client->conferences->read(), and check if the results of $conferences  is null before you try an use the  foreach on them

Comment: I tried $conferences = $client->conferences->read() and I get the same error as described at the topic at that line.

Comment: i would guess that the account or autotoke are not right , can you see if you can access your account with then like so :https://{AccountSid}:{AuthToken}@api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was in bad credentials I setted. I used test credentials that are only for REST API testing purposes. When I setted correct credentials from https://www.twilio.com/console the problem was solved. Thanks Shachaf.Gortler for the some help.

Comment: That bit me as well.  Here is an explanation of what you can/can't do with test credentials: https://www.twilio.com/docs/iam/test-credentials